# Search inside JSON's attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have a JSON like this:

```
    var parse = [
   {
      "variation_id":"34",
      "attributes":{
         "attribute_pa_rozmiar":"m"
      },
      "image_src":"http://localhost/Fraise-WP/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Jellyfish-300x300.jpg",
      "image_link":"http://localhost/Fraise-WP/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Jellyfish.jpg",
      "image_title":"Jellyfish",
      "price_html":"",
      "availability_html":"<p class=\"stock \">10 w magazynie</p>",
      "sku":"",
      "weight":"4 kg",
      "dimensions":"",
      "min_qty":1,
      "max_qty":"10",
      "backorders_allowed":false,
      "is_in_stock":true,
      "is_downloadable":false,
      "is_virtual":false,
      "is_sold_individually":"no"
   },
   {
      "variation_id":"33",
      "attributes":{
         "attribute_pa_rozmiar":"s"
      },
      "image_src":"http://localhost/Fraise-WP/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Desert-300x300.jpg",
      "image_link":"http://localhost/Fraise-WP/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Desert.jpg",
      "image_title":"Desert",
      "price_html":"",
      "availability_html":"<p class=\"stock \">5 w magazynie</p>",
      "sku":"",
      "weight":"4 kg",
      "dimensions":"",
      "min_qty":1,
      "max_qty":"5",
      "backorders_allowed":false,
      "is_in_stock":true,
      "is_downloadable":false,
      "is_virtual":false,
      "is_sold_individually":"no"
   }
][
   {
      "variation_id":"34",
      "attributes":{
         "attribute_pa_rozmiar":"m"
      },
      "image_src":"http://localhost/Fraise-WP/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Jellyfish-300x300.jpg",
      "image_link":"http://localhost/Fraise-WP/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Jellyfish.jpg",
      "image_title":"Jellyfish",
      "price_html":"",
      "availability_html":"<p class=\"stock \">10 w magazynie</p>",
      "sku":"",
      "weight":"4 kg",
      "dimensions":"",
      "min_qty":1,
      "max_qty":"10",
      "backorders_allowed":false,
      "is_in_stock":true,
      "is_downloadable":false,
      "is_virtual":false,
      "is_sold_individually":"no"
   },
   {
      "variation_id":"33",
      "attributes":{
         "attribute_pa_rozmiar":"s"
      },
      "image_src":"http://localhost/Fraise-WP/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Desert-300x300.jpg",
      "image_link":"http://localhost/Fraise-WP/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Desert.jpg",
      "image_title":"Desert",
      "price_html":"",
      "availability_html":"<p class=\"stock \">5 w magazynie</p>",
      "sku":"",
      "weight":"4 kg",
      "dimensions":"",
      "min_qty":1,
      "max_qty":"5",
      "backorders_allowed":false,
      "is_in_stock":true,
      "is_downloadable":false,
      "is_virtual":false,
      "is_sold_individually":"no"
   }
]
```

What I need is to run a search inside `attributes`, find if this Object has, for eg. `attribute_pa_rozmiar=m` and get corresponding `image_src`. Sorry for such a bloated JSON, but it's the only way I could get it out.

Comment: Can you show us how you tried?

Comment: My JSON is something like this: `var parse = [{"attributes":{"attribute_s":"s"},...]`. So I went with `$.each(parse.attributes, function(i,v) { if (v.attributes.search(new RegExp(/s/i)) != -1) {alert(v.attributes}); but it returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" in the console.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski: You want `$.[…](parse, …` then - `parse` has no `attributes` property but is an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. it's using the $.each and working fine

```
      $.each(parse, function(i, item) {
          $.each(item, function(j, innerItem){
           // perform search on innerItem.a or innerItem.b
          });
      });
```

**Updated:**

As per your new update first your JSON was invalid. You have extra ][ in the middle of the variable data. 
I've create another JSFiddle to solve your problem. See the working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/vendettamit/kjzPC/

PS - When you have to post this kinda long codes then you can use online formatter and then post it. :)

Comment: Gets me a lot of `undefined` in the console. Any idea why?

Comment: I've created a jsFiddle for the same http://jsfiddle.net/vendettamit/8Yd9A/ see it running.

Comment: I have a problem with your solution I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407097/json-parsed-attributed-duplicates-on-elements can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried running $.each and $.map functions based on found exaples, but none worked.

Try [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) instead:

```
var filtered = $.grep(parse, function(item) {
    return item.attributes.attribute_pa_rozmiar == "m";
});
var images = $.map(filtered, function(item) {
    return item.image_src;
});
```

Comment: Returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`;

Comment: Not for the object you presented. For the one you posted in the comment it would be `$.grep(parse, function(v) { return v.attributes.attribute_s.indexOf("s") != -1; })`